# How to inject dependencies in a flutter multi module project

Tags: flutter, dependency-injection, clean-architecture

I have created a project with clean architecture and I have 2 modules in it, domain and data:

```
mainProject
  - dataModule
  - domainModule
  lib
```

I'm using the injectable package to implement the dependency injection but I don't know if there is a way to implement dependency injection in this structure.